# Session lost before page load on one page but not on another

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am working on an application with similar functionality being used on many pages. I have a screen which opens a modal window and allows the user to do a search. When the user clicks on a record the record name is first saved in a session and then the parent window is asked to close the modal and then refresh.

Then on the page load of the parent I do a check to see what the value of the search text session is before I use that to do a search for the other data and populate the screen.

This setup works fine on the first screen which I developed and has not failed once. The problem is that on an additional screen which I setup in exactly the same way, at the point that the session value is checked on the page load of the parent window it is simply set to NULL and I even copied the same code from the working page to this so it should be identical.

Child window JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendval() {
            window.parent.onSave(); - Just switches off a checkdirty function.
            window.parent.location.reload(); - Reloads the parent so it can get the val on page load
        }
        </script>
```

Child window button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AddressCode") %>' OnClientClick="sendval();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Child window button method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buttonText = ((Button)sender).Text;
    Session["CustTypeVal"] = buttonText;
}
```

Parent window check for session value (this is where the session comes back as null on one page but not on another:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
//get the session variable from the open page in order to do the search.
                if (Session["CustTypeVal"] != null)
                {
                    //The method you need to run after refresh
                    SearchInvAddr((string)Session["CustTypeVal"]);
                    //Remove the session after
                    Session.Remove("CustTypeVal");
                }
}
```

I would appreciate any help on this one.

Comment: Is there more code you can share? I added my response below, but more code would be helpful for more completely answering your question. The code for the page that is not correctly fetching the Session value would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
//get the session variable from the open page in order to do the search.
                if (Session["CustTypeVal"] != null)
                {
                    //The method you need to run after refresh
                    SearchInvAddr((string)Session["CustTypeVal"]);
                    //Remove the session after
                    Session.Remove("CustTypeVal");
                }
}
```

If that's your first page, and you have the exact same code on the second page, the Session value is no longer going to exist because of

```
Session.Remove("CustTypeVal");
```

If you are using Session values, they don't have to be cleared until you log out, so there is no real need to remove them unless it could be potentially used to violate security.